# How to get only 10 documents at a time in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nodes, ejs

```
const result = student.find();
```

In mongodb database i require to get 10 documents on every buttion click and next time on click i need to get net 10 documents in mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass limit method after `student.find()`. For example if you want to limit 10 documents it'll look like this `const result = student.find().limit(10)`

Comment: What to do to get next 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps -
Step 1 - Pass limit and skip value in api query like -
baseurl/api/v1/apiendpoint?limit=10&skip=0

Step 2 - Fetch limit and skip value from url
const limit = req.query.limit;
const skip = req.query.skip;

step 3 -
const result = student.find().skip(skip).limit(limit);

Note - Limit and skip value will be change as per your click.

Comment: Skip value will be total number of documents i want to skip ? Or
It is particular document to skip ?

Comment: total number of documents you want to skip

Comment: @SIDDHARTHSINGH yes total number of documents you want to skip